# Problems in showing all scale values in a plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, axis

I have written this latex code that generates a plotting of lines.
How can i make the sides have every value instead of only the even values ? Thank you.

Code:

```
 \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            name = plot,
            xlabel=Input File,
            ylabel=Execution Time]
        \addplot[color=red, mark=*] coordinates {
            (1,0)
            (2,1)
            (3,2)
            (4,3)
            (5,4)
            (6,5)
            (7,6)
            (8,7)
            (9,8)
            (10,10)
        };\label{C}
        \addplot[color=blue, mark=*] coordinates {
            (1,1)
            (2,-1)
            (3,5)
            (4,5)
            (5,6)
            (6,3)
            (7,4)
            (8,2)
            (9,10)
            (10,4)
        };\label{Py}
        \end{axis}
        \node[anchor=north,fill=white,draw=black] (legend) at ($(plot.north)-(0 mm, 1 mm)$) {\begin{tabular}{l l}
            C & \ref{C} \\
            Py & \ref{Py}
        \end{tabular} };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: i want the values in red to go from the 1st to the last in the coordinates, not just even values]

Comment: Add options `xtick distance=1, ytick distance=1` to `axis` environment.

Answer (score 1):

The spacing of `xtick` and `ytick` can be controlled by `xtick distance` and `ytick distance`. In your case, set both to be 1:

```
\begin{axis}[
name = plot,
xtick distance=1,
ytick distance=1,
xlabel=Input File,
ylabel=Execution Time]
```

Answer (score 1):

For the interval between ticks, you can use `xtick distance=1` and `ytick distance=1`. I added `xmin=0` and `hide obscured x ticks=false` to show the x tick at abscissa 0, plus a more idiomatic way to compose the legend with the appearance you want.

The legend code uses:

- in the options of the `axis` environment: `legend style={at={([yshift=-1mm]0.5,1)}, anchor=north}` for legend placement and `legend plot pos=right` to swap the marker and label between left and right positions;
- after the respective `\addplot` commands, `\addlegendentry{C}` and `\addlegendentry{Py}`.

```latex
\documentclass[tikz, border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}       % for instance, but 1.16 works as well

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      xlabel=Input file,
      ylabel=Execution time,
      xtick distance=1,
      ytick distance=1,
      xmin=0,                      % Added to make the
      hide obscured x ticks=false, % xtick at 0 visible.
      legend style={at={([yshift=-1mm]0.5,1)}, anchor=north},
      legend plot pos=right,
      ]
  \addplot[color=red, mark=*] coordinates {
      (1,0)
      (2,1)
      (3,2)
      (4,3)
      (5,4)
      (6,5)
      (7,6)
      (8,7)
      (9,8)
      (10,10)
  };
  \addlegendentry{C}
  \addplot[color=blue, mark=*] coordinates {
      (1,1)
      (2,-1)
      (3,5)
      (4,5)
      (5,6)
      (6,3)
      (7,4)
      (8,2)
      (9,10)
      (10,4)
  };
  \addlegendentry{Py}
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]